# Is it ok that my computer vision dataset just is loads of frames and images instead of video?

Tags: dataset, computer-vision, opencv

I am new computer vision and I am having a dataset with consecutive frames of videos. I want to ask that is it okay? How will you deal with it to output a video with some detections?

Comment: Please mention more details. What is the task you are trying to solve? What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - individual frames can be used. See existing answers and links to docs as appropriate:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/18954889/1928322

The following blog shows how to extract individual frames from a video (replicating your environment) before continuing:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Video has two information *i.e. Images(Frames) and a temporal sense(moving Frame).*

- To identify an object in each frame, treating each frame as separate image will work.
- To read the temporal sense of the video *i.e. Running or Skipping*, will need to treat the video as *Sequence of images* and work accordingly.

This topic is pretty well covered in the online course of "*University of Michigan*"

[*Course Link*](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ejustincj/teaching/eecs498/FA2020/schedule.html)

Check lecture 17,18.